# Trouble spreading values using tidyjson

Tags: json, r

I am trying to convert the following multi-document JSON file into a data.frame.

```
x = '[
  {"name": "Bob","groupIds": ["kwt6x61", "yiahf43"]},
  {"name": "Sally","groupIds": "yiahf43"}
]'
```

I'm almost there by using

```
 y = x %>% gather_array() %>% 
  spread_values(
    name = jstring("name"),
    groupIds = jstring("groupIds")
  )
print(y)
```

Which returns:

```
document.id array.index  name                   groupIds
1           1           1   Bob list("kwt6x61", "yiahf43")
2           1           2 Sally                    yiahf43
```

Can someone help spread the groupsIds into addtional rows?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem.  The issue stems from the fact that an array of 1 is stored as a string.  Otherwise, `enter_object('groupIds') %>% gather_array %>% append_values_string` would work nicely.  `tidyjson` does not seem to handle this situation nicely.  I wonder whether this would even be considered valid JSON, since in one case groupIds is a string, and in another it is an array.

In any case, although this is not an ideal solution, you can use `json_types()` to illustrate the difference and then conditionally treat each.  I converted to a `tbl_df` (i.e. dropped JSON component) for future processing when done parsing.

```
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x = '[
  {"name": "Bob","groupIds": ["kwt6x61", "yiahf43"]},
  {"name": "Sally","groupIds": "yiahf43"}
 ]'

## Show the different types
z <- x %>% gather_array() %>% spread_values(
  name=jstring('name')
) %>% enter_object('groupIds') %>% json_types()

## Conditionally treat each
final <- bind_rows(
  z[z$type=='array',] %>% gather_array('id') %>% append_values_string('groupId')
  , z[z$type=='string',] %>% append_values_string('groupId') %>% mutate(id=1)
) %>% tbl_df

## Spread them out, maybe?  Depends on what you're looking for
final %>% spread('id','groupId')
```